# Fetch items from Directus Api

Tags: api, rest, translation, directus

I've one site with multilingual options and foreach language I've some different contents that are inside on Directus page Translations fields.

I already have one fetch that return all the fields that are included inside this certain Directus page:

`https://xxx/items/xxx_page?fields=*,translations.*,page_contents.translations.*,related_pages.translations.*,related_pages.*,page_contents.*&filter[languages_code]=it-IT&filter[page_contents.translations][languages_code]=it-IT`

It return all the contents and all the translations fields, but I would optimize the page load.

How can I change the fetch of the fields whith a filter for take only the fields that have a certain languages_code value.

I've already tried to use filter:

`?fields=*,page_contents.*,page_contents.translations.*&?filter[page_contents][translations][languages_code][_eq]=it-IT`

but without results.

Can someone help me?

Thanks.